# Pass options to the forked JVM

Tags: grails, jvm, fork

I'm using Grails 2.3.5 and I need to pass an option to the forked JVM.  I've tried doing this by setting the JAVA_OPTS environment variable, but that simply gets ignored by the forked JVM.  How can I go about passing the forked JVM an option?

I've found this link, which is now dead: http://jira.grails.org/browse/MAVEN-177?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel but that's if you're using the Maven plugin I believe.  I'm looking for the equivalent but without having to get Maven plugin involved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to: https://grails.github.io/grails2-doc/2.3.0/guide/single.html#forkedMode  (near the bottom of the section) you can use `jvmArgs` in your `grails.project.fork` configuration. In BuildConfig:

```
grails.project.fork = [
    // ...
    run: [maxMemory:1024, minMemory:64, debug:false, maxPerm:256, jvmArgs: '..arbitrary JVM arguments..']
    // ...
]
```

Comment: FWIW, I tried this solution (and a few others involving `--debug-fork` and directly passing JVM arguments into grails), but NOTHING worked except g'old `JAVA_OPTS=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005` (Granted, I am stuck on an older version of grails: 2.0.3.)

Answer (score 7):

Couldn't post a comment. To clarify Andrew's answer, jvmArgs has to be a list.

```
grails.project.fork = [
    // ...
    run: [maxMemory:1024, minMemory:64, debug:false, maxPerm:256, jvmArgs: ['-Dsome.prop=true', ...] ]
    // ...
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Grails 2.5.1 in forked mode running with the Tomcat 7.0.55.3 plugin, I could not get any of the `grails.project.fork.jvmArgs` solutions to work.
I eventually was able to pass JVM options to the forked process by adding this at the end of my BuildGroovy.config:

`grails.tomcat.jvmArgs = ['-jvm_option_here']`

See: [TomcatServerFactory.groovy](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-tomcat-plugin/blob/master/src/groovy/org/grails/plugins/tomcat/TomcatServerFactory.groovy#L69)