# How to debug grails applications

Tags: grails

I am currently involved in the development of an application based on grails (version `3.12`). Unfortunately I am not familiar with the ecosystem surrounding the framework. I would like to fix some bugs which are present in the code, but I am unclear about how to debug the application.

I read that remote debugging is the best bet for grails applications. This actually sort of works: I added a "Remote" execution profile in intellij and launched grails like this:

```
export GRAILS_OPTS="agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005"
grails run-app
```

This does however have the effect that I have to launch the remote twice in intellij. I figured that this is due to the fact that grails has two forks of the JVM running (one for the compilation / etc and one forthe execution). Also, apparently a new JVM is forked whenever the source code changes.

My question is: How can I get the grails options through to the right JVM process via the configuration?

I found an older similar thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21467172/1255016). This does however apply to grails 2 and not grails 3. In particular, the `buildConfig.groovy` is gone and adding things like

```
grails.project.fork = [
    // ...
    run: [maxMemory:1024, minMemory:64, debug:false, maxPerm:256, jvmArgs: '..arbitrary JVM arguments..']
    // ...
]
```

to `build.gradle` causes exceptions to be thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do what you are asking about.  One approach that doesn't involve needing to change the default generated build file or set any environment variables is the run the application like this:

```
./gradlew bootRun --debug-jvm
```

That will cause startup to pause until you connect the remote debugger.  I do that a lot.

Another option is to open `Application.groovy`, right click and select "Debug...".

Comment: Neither of those approaches require setting any special environment variables.